# Can I use this fertilizer on my Jade Plants?

Tags: fertilizer, jade

So I have never fed my jade plants in the 2 years that I have owned them and they aren't too happy. I found this universal water soluble fertilizer and was wondering if I could use it on my jade plants, would it do them any good?

It says that it can be used for vegetables as well as indoor flowers (not plants, FLOWERS) here's a picture of the label: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade plants do not need a lot of fertilizer.  From your previous questions I do not see any nutrient deficiencies.  I would wait a few months until some roots have regrown after the repotting then apply it.

Comment: ok, but in a few months if I do want to fertilize them can I use this one?

Comment: And also aren't pale leaves a sign of nutrient deficiencies? the leaves on my jade plans are pretty pale.

Comment: @Mihkel  The leaves are pale because they are not getting enough light.  As the plant has just been repotted wait for root growth and provide more light

Comment: but again in a few months if I do want to fertilize them can I use this one? I want my plants to grow big and strong

Comment: @Mihkel  Yes, you could use this fertilizer